# Why instead of string method returns Kotlin.Unit?

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a regular method which through the presenter returns String from shared preferences class. The return value is correct and shows needed value string but in activity I received Kotlin.Unit instead of that value.

Where might be the issue is?

Shared pref class is java / Activity and presenter Kotlin

[image]

Code which in result returns string

```
public String getAdTimeLeft() {
    String result = "";
    String triggerTime = getTriggertTime();
    String currentTime = AdLauncher.getInstance().getCurrentTimeAsString();
    SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
    Date triggerTimeDate = null;
    try {
        triggerTimeDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(triggerTime);
        Date currentTimeDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(currentTime);
        long difference = triggerTimeDate.getTime() - currentTimeDate.getTime();
        long days = (int) (difference / (1000*60*60*24));
        long hours = (int) ((difference - (1000*60*60*24*days)) / (1000*60*60));
        int min = (int) (difference - (1000*60*60*24*days) - (1000*60*60*hours)) / (1000*60);
        result = String.valueOf(min);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Suddenly figured out if I make a call directly from Pref class it works correct. Like this
`mTimeLeft.text = SharPrefManager.getInstance().adTimeLeft`

But through presenter not working. This is presenter code
`SharPrefManager.getInstance().getAdTimeLeft()`

Why with presenter it not working?

Comment: Please add the code for `getAdTimeLeft` method.

Comment: @BirjuVachhani added

Comment: Your `x` variable hasn't been asigned yet, go to the next line

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher i know thats just for testing purpose to check separate returning value

Comment: @a_local_nobody yes it goes inside that method and correctly calculates on each step. after that return the right result with right type. So i guess something might be wrong on kotlin side

Comment: @a_local_nobody  yes that awhat I do

Comment: @a_local_nobody you cant do that. method suppose to ends with `()`

Comment: @a_local_nobody lol without presenter it works fine. if i call directly from activity

Comment: @a_local_nobody found the solution.... check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was missed return state. By default Kotlin leave it as UNIT thats why as result I received kotlin.Unit text. The solution change looks like this

I changed presenter

```
fun grabAdTimeLeft(): String? {
    return SharPrefManager.getInstance().grabAdTimeLeft()
}
```

Comment: hello. Now I have the same problem. Could you please explain...